# Wireless not functional

Tags: wireless

I am a complete newcomer to Ubuntu.

Today I installed Ubuntu 12.04 onto an 3 or 4 year old laptop - an HP DV2221. Install went fine, except that I can't get the wireless card to operate. I see that there are drivers installed (Broadcom STA wireless) and it says they are activated, but the wireless light on the body of the computer is lit as orange, when it should be blue, and if I disconnect the Ethernet wire, there is no ability to get onto Firefox.

I've looked at some of the similar questions on this site, as well as Googling the issue - mostly, I guess I don't understand how to navigate or do some of the fixes recommended - I'm fairly adept technologically around Windows, but know zilch about Linux and how to perform some of the fixes - so, if possible, please tell me how I get to the menus needed to rectify the situation.

Comment: What kind of wireless router do you have? Have you changed any of its settings other than the password, *especially DHCP and DNS stuff*?

Comment: I have a 2 wire router - it works with my other laptop and worked with this one up until the Ubuntu install - I don't think the laptop's wireless antenna is working, I have not gotten to the point of trying to connect to a router.

Comment: It may e a software failure to communicate with the router. Please do tell about its settings and what router it is.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your question - which settings are you referring to and how to I determine them?

Comment: I only need to know if you manually *changed them*. If the settings are at their defaults(you never manually changed them) there is no need to tell the specific settings. Also, I really need to know the router model.

Comment: no change in settings.  2 Wire 3801 HGV

Comment: OK. Thanks! That may help other users (sorry, but I am not good with wireless networking) to fix your problem.

Comment: FWIW there are other available networks that my windows laptop sees as options.  No networks - mine or my neighbors are seen by the Ubunu machine - I don't know what those routers are.

Answer (score 1):

answer turned out to be that I needed to remove the additional drivers - when I uninstalled them, the wireless became functional.